# Characterization of the homotopy type of the $C^\infty$ topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology

One of the subtle aspects of geometric topology is the interaction of function space topologies and homotopy theory. There are many reasonable topologies to put on the space of smooth embeddings $\mathrm{Emb}(M,N)$ which are sometimes homotopy equivalent, but not always. Define $\mathrm{Fr}_d(M)$ to be the bundle of $d$-frames of $M$. Let us call a topology $\tau$ on $\mathrm{Emb}(M,N)$ "reasonable" if the derivative map $\mathrm{Emb}^\tau(\mathbb{R}^d,N) \rightarrow \mathrm{Fr}_d(M)$ is continuous and a homotopy equivalence.

Is there, in any sense, a way to characterize the $C^\infty$-topology on $\mathrm{Emb}(M,N)$, or its homotopy type in the poset of reasonable topologies, as some type of universal reasonable topology? I interpret the work of Goodwillie-Klein-Weiss in [Spaces of smooth embeddings,
disjunction and surgery](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/tda/goodwilliekleinweiss.pdf) which shows that $\mathrm{Emb}(-,N)$ is convergent in the sense of manifold calculus, as a positive answer in codimension >2, but I expect there are much simpler approaches which might use a different type of homotopy sheaf condition which is easier to check.

Comment: What if you define a topology like the Whitney C^infty topology, but instead of the usual topology on the jet bundles, every fiber above dimension 1 has the indiscrete topology. Then this defines a courser topology than the usual one. To me it looks like it still gives a homotopy equivalence from embeddings to the frame bundle (since that part of the topology is preserved).

Comment: @ChrisSchommer-Pries Thanks for the example! A different way to express what I am after is "Are there natural conditions I can put on such a topology so $\mathrm{Emb}^\tau(M,N)$ is homotopy equivalent to the $C^\infty$-topology?" I expect in this case your example is homotopy equivalent since generally $C^k$ contains the same homotopical information as $C^\infty$ if $k>0$.